# What is the use of the colon in variable declaration?

Tags: declaration, var, gdscript

In GDscript, what is the difference between this two variable declarations?

```
extends Node

var n = 10
var m: = 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one `var n = 10` is an assignment but `n` has no type. The second one `var m: = 10` is also an assignment but `m` now is an integer.

The second one is equal to:

```
var m: int
m = 10
```

For more info you can read [this](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html).